# FFmpeg raw 10-bit frame to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have a single frame stored in file '2.raw' which has an 128 bit float format for each color.
Can I create a H.265 10-bit video with it?

```
ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gbrapf32be -s:v 3072:1536 -i 2.raw -c:v libx265 output.mp4

ffmpeg version git-2019-12-11-4110029 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20191125
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 36.101 / 56. 36.101
  libavcodec     58. 64.101 / 58. 64.101
  libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.101 / 58.  9.101
  libavfilter     7. 68.100 /  7. 68.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
[rawvideo @ 000001a1547dc780] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from '2.raw':
  Duration: 00:00:01.12, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15099494 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, gbrapf32be, 3072x1536, 15099494 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> hevc (libx265))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'Parsed_null_0' and the filter 'auto_scaler_0'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Function not implemented
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
```

I'm trying to see what file will ffmpeg can create which would support a 10-bit H265 encoding.

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Okay, done @Gyan

Comment: You may start with the following command: `ffmpeg -y -r 10 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gbrapf32be -video_size 3072x1536 -i 2.raw -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -x265-params profile=main10 output.mp4`. You are probably not going to get a very nice result....